# getting only normal layout for all screen size

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create app for all screen size, i'm creating different layout folder as below

```
layout
layout-sw480dp
layout-sw600dp
layout-sw720dp
layout-xlarge
```

and set appropriate screen size margin and enable support screen size in manifest file but problem is that when i'm running my app it's run normal default layout for any of screen size when i'm doing wrong please tell me.

in manifest i include

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

and

```
    <activity android:name="com.myproject.demo"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|screenLayout" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">

    </activity>
```

According PercentRelativeLayout

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradiant"
>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
        app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginRightPercent="5%"
        app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_marginBottomPercent="22%"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageBack"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/card1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:layout_heightPercent="15%"
                android:src="@drawable/ps"
                android:id="@+id/imageViewd"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="8%" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sndmulmsg"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@layout/mybuttons"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="40px"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageBack"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_marginBottomPercent="2%"

                 />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mulmono"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="Enter No&apos;s 91**********,91**********"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:lines="2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewd"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout5"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/madd"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/madd"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="7%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="3%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3%">
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/madd"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                app:layout_widthPercent="17%"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@layout/mybuttons"
                android:text="@string/addcontact"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mulmono"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mulmsg"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/mulmsg"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="3%" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Schedule"
                android:id="@+id/schedule"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mulmsg"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="3%" />



            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/mulflash"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Flash"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mulmsg"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="6%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/sndmulmsg"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mulmsg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="Enter Your Message here..!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="3"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/mulmono"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                app:layout_marginTopPercent="5%"
                app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3%"
                app:layout_marginRightPercent="3%" />
        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `PercentRelativeLayout` or `PercentFrameLayout` with single layout file. You can't create 100 layout files if you want to support 100 devices. Smart solution is to use percent layouts.

Comment: Thanks @ Mohammed Atif it's work for me

Comment: hey PercentRelativeLayout works for some button for me but when i'm trying for edittext and image it appears not well on different device can you please help or any another way to make responsive app for all devices.

Comment: Can you upload the code where you are facing the problem?

Comment: I've  edit my code as per your guidence i use android percent relative layout but still i'm not getting well output for all devices. guide me when i doing wrong thanks in advance. @mohammed atif

Comment: Can you also provide the screenshot or image if the screen that you exactly want. Currently there are few things in your code that must not have been done, once you provide the expected screen image, I can provide you with full xml.

Comment: i try to upload image but currently i'm not abel to upload image on stack overflow.

Comment: or else i can mail you screen shot what exactly i need if you don't mind then give me mail id thanks in advance

Comment: You can upload the image on any social media with public access or github and share the link here

Comment: Please refer this link , hear i've attached image which layout i want to create https://github.com/NDBNeer/android/issues/1

Comment: Ok @zilu,  i saw your design, and for this I have one recommendation. According to material designs guidelines, any screen that has 1. login/registration, 2. scrollabe items, 3. lists/grids, should not be resized according to screen because of their scrolling behaviour they occupy the necessary space automatically. So yoi don't need to make your layouts responsive. But if you want to build a screen outside thr google guidelines, then let me know, i will upload an answer with responsive UI xml.

Comment: @mohammed atif thanks for guidance but i also need responsive ui xml.

Comment: hello sir...you are there?  
@mohammed atif

Comment: Sure zilu, I will update the xml in answer once I get the time.

Comment: ok sir,thank you@mohammed atif

Comment: hello..! any update or any hint because when i use percent layout it will not  show in some phones like sdous2 ,intex.

Comment: you only need that login screem only right?